# can't set PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape from MS Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project, page-setup

Using VBA in MS Project 2003 I create an Excel sheet and write data to it.
After that I want to change SetPrintArea and Orientation of the sheet I created so I wrote

```
with xlsheet                         '// Defined being an Excel.Worksheet
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        .Columns(i).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next i
    txtPrintArea = txtPrintArea & "$" & xlCol.Row  '// I created the range to print before
    With .PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PrintArea = xlSheet.UsedRange.Address
    End With
End With
```

It crashes at the .Orientation statement.
If I comment that out it crashes at the .PrintArea line.
My conclusion is it can't set any property of .PageSetup

How can I specify the PrintArea ?

Comment: If you step through your code, can you see the PrintArea and Orientation properties on xlSheet.PageSetup in the watch window?

Comment: Also, you don't need the loop in your code to set the column widths. You can just use the one line: .UsedRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Comment: .UsedRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit is better indeed. But in my 'real code' I only need part of .UsedRange so I just removed the starting column from the loop to simplify the code i posted here.

Comment: In the watch window I can see xlSheet.PageSetup I can see the names of its properties but it says "<Unable to get Orientation property of of the PageSetup class>"  Almost all properties have similar entries. If look at xlSheet.PageSetup.Application.Activeprinter : see "unknown printer (check your Control Panel)"  I do not have a printer defined on this PC but that shouldn't make a difference AFAIK

Comment: Hmmmm. Is there any difference if you do install a printer on the PC?

Comment: I am facing similar problem. Does installing printer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I installed BullZip PDF printer and after that .PageSetup.Orientation works.
So it seems PageSetup NEEDS a printer to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right thing.

Why do you set txtPrintArea but then set the .PrintArea = xlSheet.UsedRange.Address ???

Otherwise you'll need to post more code as an example.  I created the following based on your question and it worked for me:

```
Set xlSheet = Sheet1
Set xlCol = Sheet1.Rows(1)
txtPrintArea = "A"
With xlSheet                         '// Defined being an Excel.Worksheet
    xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    txtPrintArea = txtPrintArea & "$" & Trim(Str(xlCol.Row)) + ":b2"   '// I created the range to print before
    With .PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PrintArea = txtPrintArea '//xlSheet.UsedRange.Address
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Same problem : crash at .Orientation = xlLandscape            
txtPrintArea has not been used (exchanged by UsedRange) for testing (avoid POSSIBLE problem because of wrong definition of txtPrintArea)
'More code'?? Don't know what you are missing (of course xlSheet and xlCol have been set before using them) , it is about not being able to set properties of xlSheet.PageSetup

Comment: Were you able to run my example above?  If so, then I would then reduce your code to the bare essentials.  What happens if you run: xlsheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape ???

Comment: I've not been able to run your code (crashes). Also xlsheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape doesn't make a difference