# Issue when generating a PDF via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF via VBA. I am using the below code:

```vb
Sub test_A()
  Dim i, j As Integer
  Dim chemin_dossier As Variant

  chemin_dossier = Range("q2")

  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=chemin_dossier & " Inc_claim-TEST " 

end
```

The VBA code works very well on my PC, but on my colleagues' computers I receive have the below "Error 400":

[image: Screenshot of error message]

When I use the VBA debugger (F8) the problem is associated with the following:

```vb
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=chemin_dossier & " Inc_claim-TEST "
```

I do not understand why the code works when I use it, while it does not work when my colleagues use it. We are using the same path, the same Excel file, the same VBA code.

Can I generate PDF without the method:

```vb
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
```

Comment: Note that if you `Dim i, j As Integer` then `j` is `Integer` but `i` is `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable, I also recommend to use `Long` instead: `Dim i As Long, j As Long` • [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Please add the result of `Debug.Print chemin_dossier & " Inc_claim-TEST "` in case of the error to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests and was unable to recreate your issue. So I did a little digging and came across this. Not sure if it will help, but it seemed like it could.
[ExportAsFixedFormat fails sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857728/exportasfixedformat-fails-sometimes)